# RxJava as event bus?

Tags: android, android-fragments, rx-java, event-bus

I'm start learning RxJava and I like it so far. I have a fragment that communicate with an activity on button click (to replace the current fragment with a new fragment). Google recommends [interface](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html) for fragments to communicate up to the activity but it's too verbose, I tried to use broadcast receiver which works generally but it had drawbacks.

Since I'm learning RxJava I wonder if it's a good option to communicate from fragments to activities (or fragment to fragment)?. If so, whats the best way to use RxJava for this type of communication?. Do I need to make event bus like this [one](http://nerds.weddingpartyapp.com/tech/2014/12/24/implementing-an-event-bus-with-rxjava-rxbus/) and if that's the case should I make a single instance of the bus and use it globally (with subjects)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes and it's pretty amazing after you learn how to do it. Consider the following singleton class:

```
public class UsernameModel {

    private static UsernameModel instance;

    private PublishSubject<String> subject = PublishSubject.create();

    public static UsernameModel instanceOf() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new UsernameModel();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    /**
     * Pass a String down to event listeners.
     */
    public void setString(String string) {
        subject.onNext(string);
    }

    /**
     * Subscribe to this Observable. On event, do something e.g. replace a fragment
     */
    public Observable<String> getStringObservable() {
        return subject;
    }

}
```

In your Activity be ready to receive events (e.g. have it in the onCreate):

```
UsernameModel usernameModel = UsernameModel.instanceOf();

//be sure to unsubscribe somewhere when activity is "dying" e.g. onDestroy
subscription = usernameModel.getStringObservable()
        .subscribe(s -> {
            // Do on new string event e.g. replace fragment here
        }, throwable -> {
            // Normally no error will happen here based on this example.
        });
```

In you Fragment pass down the event when it occurs:

```
UsernameModel.instanceOf().setString("Nick");
```

Your activity then will do something.

Tip 1: Change the String with any object type you like.

Tip 2: It works also great if you have Dependency injection.

---

**Update:** 
I wrote a more lengthy [article](https://lorentzos.com/rxjava-as-event-bus-the-right-way-10a36bdd49ba)

Comment: 1. Your example would be better off with a `BehaviorSubject` to make observing this "sticky". i.e. new subscriptions will see the last value. You probably want that as then new Views that depend on the value will update correctly upon subscription.
2. `UsernameModel` really does one thing only: wraps a `PublishSubject` and makes it a singleton. DI offers singletons! If you were using DI you would just inject the `PublishSubject` or `BehaiorSubject` directly. If you're using Dagger, then you can use `@Named("username")` to inject the `Subject`.

Comment: similar implementation [check below answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48300275/4647628)

Answer (score 3):

Currently I *think* my preferred approach to this question is this to:

1.) Instead of one global bus that handles everything throughout the app (and consequently gets quite unwieldy) use "local" buses for clearly defined purposes and only plug them in where you need them.

For example you might have:

- One bus for sending data between your `Activity`s and your `ApiService`.
- One bus for communicating between several `Fragment`s in an `Activity`.
- One bus that sends the currently selected app theme color to all `Activity`s so that they can tint all icons accordingly.

2.) Use Dagger (or maybe AndroidAnnotations if you prefer that) to make the wiring-everything-together a bit less painful (and to also avoid lots of `static` instances). This also makes it easier to, e. g. have a single component that deals only with storing and reading the login status in the `SharedPreferences` - this component could then also be wired directly to your `ApiService` to provide the session token for all requests.

3.) Feel free to use `Subject`s internally but "cast" them to `Observable` before handing them out to the public by calling `return subject.asObservable()`. This prevents other classes from pushing values into the `Subject` where they shouldn't be allowed to.

Comment: Really I wonder, what is the point of having multiple instances of an event bus? It doesn't contribute to high cohesion. Instead of one instance, you will end up multiple instances of the same thing without any real benefit.

Comment: @Gunhan Less casting around. A specific bus has a specific communication model. If you need to listen for "SomeObject" changes, why send SomeObjects through the same bus where "SomeOtherObject" may be traveling. Concrete buses are dedicated multi-layer lanes of specific information.

Answer (score 0):

> Define events

```
public class Trigger {

public Trigger() {
}

public static class Increment {
}

public static class Decrement {
}

public static class Reset {
}
}
```

> Event controller

```
public class RxTrigger {

private PublishSubject<Object> mRxTrigger = PublishSubject.create();

public RxTrigger() {
    // required
}

public void send(Object o) {
    mRxTrigger.onNext(o);
}

public Observable<Object> toObservable() {
    return mRxTrigger;
}
// check for available events
public boolean hasObservers() {
    return mRxTrigger.hasObservers();
}
}
```

> Application.class

```
public class App extends Application {

private RxTrigger rxTrigger;

public App getApp() {
    return (App) getApplicationContext();
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    rxTrigger = new RxTrigger();
}


public RxTrigger reactiveTrigger() {
    return rxTrigger;
}


}
```

> Register event listener wherever required

```
               MyApplication mApp = (App) getApplicationContext();
               mApp
                    .reactiveTrigger() // singleton object of trigger
                    .toObservable()
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()) // push to io thread
                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()) // listen calls on main thread
                    .subscribe(object -> { //receive events here
                        if (object instanceof Trigger.Increment) {
                            fabCounter.setText(String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(fabCounter.getText().toString()) + 1));
                        } else if (object instanceof Trigger.Decrement) {
                            if (Integer.parseInt(fabCounter.getText().toString()) != 0)
                                fabCounter.setText(String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(fabCounter.getText().toString()) - 1));
                        } else if (object instanceof Trigger.Reset) {
                            fabCounter.setText("0");
                        }
                    });
```

> Send/Fire event

```
 MyApplication mApp = (App) getApplicationContext();
 //increment
 mApp
    .reactiveTrigger()
    .send(new Trigger.Increment());

 //decrement
 mApp
    .reactiveTrigger()
    .send(new Trigger.Decrement());
```

Full implementation for above library with example -> [RxTrigger](https://github.com/Aks-4125/RxTrigger)

Comment: What is the purpose of `subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())`?

Comment: it's optional, subscribeOn,observeOn unless you want to perform some operations in background thread.